# Error when trying to parse CSV data into a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I am very new to C, but have an assignment for college to complete, so please forgive any stupidity in this question.

I am trying to parse a CSV into structs. When I run the following code, I get no problems in compiling, and it runs fine (albeit only printing out the results, and not assigning them to the structs):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Structs
struct Course {
    char *course_name[50];
    int grade;
};

struct Student {
    char* name;
    struct Course;
    int index;
};

char *dataArr[6] = {"Intro to Programming","Databases","Computer Architecture","Ethics in Computer Science","Advanced Programming","Puzzles and Problem Solving"};

// Expand this section for the initial interactivity
// =============================================================================================
void Import_and_Print()
{
    printf("\nPlace for importing files and printing results.\n\n");
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int in_grade;
    int i = 0;
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *token;
    char *sName;
    int j;

    //fp = fopen("CTASample.csv", "r");
    fp = fopen("Sample2.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    read = getline(&line, &len, fp);
    
    j = 0;
    
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        char *csvData = line;
        token = strtok(csvData,s);
        i = 0;
        
        while (token != NULL) {
            
            if (isalpha(token[0]) != 0) {
                strcpy(sName, token);
                printf("Student name: %s\n", sName); 
            }
            
            else {
                int in_grade = atoi(token);
                //printf("%0.f\n", in_grade);
                //printf("\n");
                printf("Course: %s\tGrade: %i\n", dataArr[i], in_grade);
                //struct Course course = {dataArr[i], in_grade};
                //struct Student name = {sName, {dataArr[i], in_grade}};
                i++;
                
            }
 
            token = strtok(NULL, s);

        fflush(stdin);
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }  
}
```

However, if I change the last commented line to be uncommented, I get the following error:

> Grades.c: In function ‘Import_and_Print’: Grades.c:64:60: warning:
> initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer
> without a cast [-Wint-conversion]    64 |                 struct
> Student name = {sName, {dataArr[i], in_grade}};
> |                                    ^~~~~~~~ Grades.c:64:60: note: (near initialization for
> ‘name..course_name[1]’)

The csv file looks like this:

```
Intro to Programming,Databases,Computer Architecture,Ethics in Computer Science,Advanced Programming,Puzzles and Problem Solving
James Jameson,80,70,55,12,50,80
Peter Parker,50,55,50,50,50,50
Mary Janeson,40,40,40,23,40,45
```

Any suggestions on how I can resolve, so that the values from the csv are inputted into the struct correctly?

Comment: Aside: note that `fflush()` is undefined on a stream opened for input.

Comment: Also, the (commented out) `struct`s defined within the `else` code block will go out of scope at the end of the block.

Comment: Just skimming through the data and code shows that the code expects a comma (`,`) separator (`const char s[2] = ","`) while the data has a pipe secretor (`|`)... consider updating the separator in the program... (`const char s[2] = "|"`)

Comment: @Myst - I've editted the OP to show the correct input. Not sure why it showed pipes, as the file is commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you format the compiler error correctly, this little "ASCII art" `^~~~~~~~` is the "here is your bug" indicator, an arrow often pointing out the exact location of the bug:

```
struct Student name = {sName, {dataArr[i], in_grade}};
|                                          ^~~~~~~~
```

Nested initialization with braces in C is tricky, because the language is lax with brace placement. We should always use braces when initializing so called *aggregates*, meaning container types like arrays and structs.

The `{dataArr[i], in_grade}` is supposedly an initializer list for a struct, but the first member of that struct is an array which you didn't surround with braces.

`dataArr[i]` initializes the first element in the array correctly since it has the correct type `char*`, but then the compiler thinks `in_grade` is used for initializing the second item in that array. Hence "initialization of ‘char *’ from ‘int’".

Simply add additional braces:

```
struct Student name = {sName, { {dataArr[i]}, in_grade}};
```

Please note however that this initialization list is still strange and sloppy: it only initializes the first item of the `course_name` array and it doesn't initialize `index` explicitly, so that one gets set to zero implicitly.

The "pro tip" for making the code more readable is *designated initializers* and proper indention:

```
struct Student name = 
{
  .name = sName, 
  .Course = 
  { 
    .course_name = { [0] = dataArr[i] }, // make it explicit that you init index 0 only
    .grade = in_grade,
  },
  .index = something;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. That is very succinct and understandable.